# Multiple link traverse for the same tag in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**Hi**

**I have below xml and i am trying to write xslt. In this XML there are books in which there might be Movie tags. So whenever the tag is inline-data and content-type is Movie i have to traverse that tag and it should show like**

**1st Link**

(A [Movie](http://video1.mpg) of this book is available here.)

**2nd Link**

(picture icon) [Movie](http://Video1.mpg)

**So there will be two links for each book which will display in different locations in site. The problem with me is how to keep the track of movie name once the traverse is done. I am not able to traverse second time for the same book. How to use the variable or flag for the same. Please can anyone provide the XSLT for the same.**

**Input XML**

```
<Book><body>
<movie  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <caption>
        <p>Testing data</p>
        <p>
            (A
            <inline-data
                content-type="Movie"  xlink:href="video1.mpg"
                xlink:title="Movie" xlink:type="simple">Movie
            </inline-data>
            of this Part is available here.)
        </p>
    </caption>
</movie>
<movie  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <caption>
        <p>Testing data</p>
        <p>
            (This movie
            <inline-data
                content-type="Movie"  xlink:href="video2.mpg"
                xlink:title="Movie" xlink:type="simple">Movie
            </inline-data>
             is available here.)
        </p>
    </caption>
</movie>
</body></Book>
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML you want to create for the XML sample you have posted? Generally if you want to process the same node several times you simply define templates with different modes (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes) and then apply-templates for those modes you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="Book">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="body/movie">
        <xsl:for-each select="//movie">
          <p><xsl:apply-templates select="caption/p[2]"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <html>
          <head><title>Movie</title></head>
          <body>
            <xsl:text>No Movie present</xsl:text>
          </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="inline-data">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```